# Layout Shrinking When The Page Has An Iframe

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe

I have a React website (based on Next.js) for which I wrote a React component to embed Tweets. But when a page contains a tweet, the layout shrinks. I have figured out that it happens when there is an iframe on the page as the Twitter API loads an iframe.

I have no clue what is happening and why my viewport settings are not being respected.

**Viewport**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
```

**Ideal Layout**

[image: Ideal layout]

**Shrunken layout (when there is a tweet on the page). Notice the toolbar and text size(s).**

[image: Shrunken layout]

*PS: The same thing happens, if I embed a YouTube video.*

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? You haven't shown any of the code you are using, it's hard to just guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe there are better options that an iframe. But, did you gave the iframe a width? for example: <iframe style="width:100%">... ?

Answer (score 0):

Without code, my best guess is your HTML or body font-size might be unset. Are you using rem or em? This could be affected by the iframe styles being embedded into your react app if it's not set properly in your react app styles.

Answer (score 0):

probably due to the overlapping of the CSS coming from the embedded code, you could debug the CSS using the developer's tools (recommend google's), and try using  `!important` in the classes to overlap the coming code from the embedded code.

example:

```
 .p {
   font-size:16px !important;
}
```